# Shared informations between users

Tags: php

I have a (php) web page that is executed each second to test if a specific datetime is reached.

This specific date time `info` is used by many users. I'm using a text file to put this `info`. So this text file is opened, closed each second and access to hard disk (to use the file) consumes time.

I wan't to make this process faster (because it takes some times more than one second) that uses RAM for exemple. So I'm looking for other support to save the `info` and keep it shared between different users.

I thought to use php sessions but this `info` will not be shared between users (each user see its own session infos).
I can use database but I don't know if it will be faster than accessing file on hard disk.

Comment: Use some in-memory cache, like redis, apcu, memcached or similar.

Comment: And to reduce the wasted processing look at the time and if the time you want is not for 10 hours then dont schedule the script again for 9 hrs 55 minutes

Comment: To be honest this sounds like a complete waste of time, so maybe if you shared your code we may understand better whats actually going on here

Comment: How do the users get this info?  Is it when they load the page or you have some AJAX that does it?

Comment: @AbraCadaver something like ajax (page executed each 1 second) to verify if a specific datetime (that can be set by any other user) is reached.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson thanks for your answer I did some research and in-memory cache should help.